# Как убедиться, что корутина сработала и завершилась?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, mobile-development

Есть кусок кода:

```
private fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
        if (tasksList[position].crossed) {
            tasksViewModel.updateTask(
                TasksModel(tasksList[position].id, tasksList[position].text, false)
            )
        } else {
            tasksViewModel.updateTask(
                TasksModel(tasksList[position].id, tasksList[position].text, true)
            )
        }
            tasksViewModel.getAllTasks()
    }
```

Он меняет событие в зависимости от того, зачёркнуто оно или нет. В конце я вызываю метод getAllTasks(), который подгружает все данные в RecyclerView чтобы обновить изменения в записи.
Если запускать программу через Debuger, всё работает. Однако если запускать программу в обычном режиме то запись изменяется с 3-4 раза, хотя событие точно срабатывает (Проверял по тостам). Как понять почему не работает обновление RecyclerView?

```
fun getAllTasks(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            readAllData.postValue(repository.getAllTasks())
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что делает `tasksViewModel.updateTask()` и в каком потоке?

Comment: fun updateTask(task: TasksModel){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.updateTask(task)
        }
    }